# Shared Preferences won't save the data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm new to Android, and a bit to Java (Don't ask)

I want to use the Shared Preferences, and till to this day everything worked fine, but in my new project the shared preferences won't save the data.

In my onCreate Method I have following code:

```
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    preferences.getFloat(TESTEPFLOAT, 0);
    preferences.getFloat(TESTCURRENTEPFLOAT, 0);
    preferences.getInt(TESTLEVEL, 1);
```

in my onDestroy Method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    editor.putInt(TESTLEVEL, level);
    editor.putFloat(TESTEPFLOAT, ep);
    editor.putFloat(TESTCURRENTEPFLOAT, currentEP);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I don't know where the problem is, and I hope someone can help me

Comment: you have to commit your editor after updating data.

Comment: @SushilKumar: apply() works like commit(), only async.

Comment: add those list in onStop not in ondestroy

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i didn't see apply. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this:

```
preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getFloat(TESTEPFLOAT, 0);
preferences.getFloat(TESTCURRENTEPFLOAT, 0);
preferences.getInt(TESTLEVEL, 1);
```

to save your data:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(TESTLEVEL, level);
        editor.putFloat(TESTEPFLOAT, ep);
        editor.putFloat(TESTCURRENTEPFLOAT, currentEP);
        editor.apply();
}
```

or use `editor.commit();` to save data immediately

Comment: How is it different than OP's code? Absolutely no change.

Comment: The difference is that at read you don't need the "editor" and at the save you can use "commit" to save data immediately and will called onPause

Comment: that is not even used. Probably just an initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use onDestroy(). There's no guarantee it will get called. If you put a break point in that method, my guess is it's not getting called when you think it is.

Comment: I agree, this also maybe a problem.

Comment: How is no garantee that onDestroy is called ? I think that onStop() is not always is called but onDestroy() should be called when the activity is destroyed ?

Comment: onPause is always called. It's the best place for this job

Comment: The documentation literally says not to use onDestroy() for saving data: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Gavin Wright said, `onDestroy` don't get called everytime. Move the code to `onPause()`. `onPause()` is guaranteed to get called everytime you navigate away from your activity.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    editor.putInt(TESTLEVEL, level);
    editor.putFloat(TESTEPFLOAT, ep);
    editor.putFloat(TESTCURRENTEPFLOAT, currentEP);
    editor.apply();
}
```